# $_POST variables not passing PHP

Tags: php, variables, post

I know there's plenty of other questions on this subject but it's not specific, I also had the page working when using mysql rather than mysqli, I've recently amended some web pages with mysqli so was updating to keep it consistent.
I've played around with things like double quotes, the mysqli_real_escape_string but the output of the $sql string is SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE username='' and password='' so it's clearly a problem with the $_POST[] variables.

Any help is much appreciated.

My code for the form to post is ;

```
<?php 
 session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="300" border="0" align="Center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="="#cccccc">
<tr>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="../customers/checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width = "100%" border ="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><p><Strong> CUSTOMER LOGIN </strong></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width = "78">Username</td>
<td widith = "6">:</td>
<td width = "294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">   </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

<form id="form2" name="logo" method="post" action="../customers/logout.php">
<input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Whilst the other page is;

```
 <?php 
ob_start();
    session_start();
    echo session_id();

$host = "localhost";
$username="username";
$password = "password";
$db_name = "database";
$tbl_name = "user_login";

//Connect to server and select database
//mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password") or die("Cannot connect");
//mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("Cannot select Database");

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

/*if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]))
{
    die("you are already logged in");
}*/ // I had put this in but removed to debug

//username and password sent from the form, I have also tried with double quotes
$myusername = $_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword = $_POST['mypassword'];

//security to stop insertion of slashs

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
ob_clean();
if($count==1){
    //register $myusername and $mypassword and redirect to the file
    $_SESSION["loggedin"]= "YES";
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
//      $_SESSION["Hotel_Chain"] = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT Hotel_Group FROM user_login WHERE username = '".$username."'");
header("Location: login_success.php"); 
exit();}

//  echo "it worked";   }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        echo $sql;
        echo "<br /> Username : ";
        echo $myusername;
        echo "<br /> Password : ";
        echo $mypassword;
    }
//  ob_flush();
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Check Login</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
if($_SESSION["loggedin"]<>"YES"){echo $count;
echo $sql;
?>
<form id="form5" name="backtomain" method="post" action="../customers/main_login.php">
<input type="Submit" name="backtomain" value="Try again" />
</form>    
<?php
}
else{
//  print mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
}
?>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're creating a `mysqli` object, then using non-object methods. [Pick a style](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) *(under examples)*.

Comment: If you want to know what is in $_POST, after you post, do something like var_dump($_POST) then let us know if post was really empty.

Comment: On a non-question-related note: don't use tables for layout, it bloats your code, makes it harder to maintain. Tables are for tabular data.

Comment: Moreover, I remember there was a time it MADE a difference whether `<form>` and `</form>` was inside or outside `<table>` and `</table>`. Don't remember the browser though.

Comment: where are the non object methods in the code? I can't find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use simple quote and concatenation.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username="'.$myusername.'" AND password="'.$mypassword.'";
```

Try to print your variables before and after every function who change its.
Easy to understand what happens.

Comment: that didn't work either, should have said I already tried that and it doesn't work. I echoed the variables and they come back empty. [EDIT] I've echoed immediately after the line $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; to echo $mypassword . " Password"; and nothing appeared, does this mean there's a problem in the header somewhere?

Comment: Of course it did not help, using double quotes and putting variables directly in it is valid PHP

Comment: The OP needs to read the comments. Especially the part about using object methods with non-object code.

Comment: Sorry NJK I did reply in that bit of the comments about the non-object method, I can't find it

Comment: Seemingly uncommenting the //ob_flush() has made it work.  Still unsure where the non-object methods are in the code.  I'll check bakc periodically so I don't make the mistake again.